# How to change Facebook FanPage "Tab" Icon via Api

Tags: facebook

I know i can have iframe tabs which in fact are apps. And for apps i can set icons.

But, imagine i have a app which is used by many fan pages to make it easier to integrate content.

There must be some dirty trick to set these icons based on the fan-page the app is included. For example http://blog.tabsite.com/post/376/Customize-Your-Fan-Page-Icon-with-TabSite makes exactly that.

Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research i have found the way. you have to use the old legacy javascript api with admin.createApplication to create a new application via script, then you can use old rest api (had no luck with the new one) to set the "appProperties" accordingly. like icon, iframe url and so on.

Comment: ¿Can't this be done with the new API? I doubt what will happen if the legacy API is removed in the future...

Comment: @Rufinus - is there a way to set a different icon for each user? (eg to have a count as a part of the icon)

Comment: @Andypandy on the "new" pages each page-admin can set the image for the tab link. the icon itself stays with the application. i dont know of a way to set it for different users. (some free html-tab apps have dozen apps registered with different icons, but tab url is always the same, so their users can choose which icon the wanna use)

Answer (score 1):

it's long time from your discussion and I am sure everyone knows the solution now.. but maybe for new visitors so sad as I was... here is link to new facebook api easily solving this...:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Comment: sorry to dissapoint you, but his is only the icon itself, this works since a long time. Take a look at all the other images/icons you can set for an app nowadays, you cant set them via api. (beside the 16x16 icon).

My Question is mainly irrelevant now, as the question was postet befor tab layout change. now a user can change the image on the fanpage itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your tab icon if you are the developer of that certain application that you are using on you tab, you can change that at developer page under your application setting.

Comment: i know, and this is exactly what i wrote above, BUT the question is there must be a way to do it on a fanpage relevant way, see tabsite.com

Comment: No, tab icon is defend on application setting. I think the link your posting above is the old facebook fanpage layout.

Comment: the link is from a application which do exactly what i trying todo. and if you look closly the example picutre "about.com" shows the new layout. (btw ifrmae apps are only possible on the new layout)

Comment: look at my fan page http://www.facebook.com/pages/filsatcom-Fan-page/284930467368?sk=app_4949752878, i change my 2 icon after pacquiao vs mosley.

Comment: i know how to change the icons. this is not the question. you can add an application to multiple fanpages, and also have different content in the tabs based on configuration. but  you can change the icons only for the application itself, not for the page the app is on. but tabsite.com claims they can do it. i build something very similar to their app for my fanpages, but i cant find a way to change the icon depending on the fanpage.